# Add attribute "on the fly" during mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT avg(round({$cohort1}/{$cohort2} * 100)) as overall_average,
`category`, `value`, {$cohort1},{$cohort2},`group`,
`quadrant`,round({$cohort1}/{$cohort2} * 100) as index_value 
from {$table};
```

This doesn't quite work perfectly when I include the average piece. That returns only one row. I need it to return all rows. If I remove the average piece, then it all returns fine, but I don't have the average for calculations. I could get this with a separate query in my PHP though.

However, I realize that I need to derive the value of quadrant(a string) based on values of the cohorts. These would be the rules. The problem is that I have no idea how to incorporate this into my query.

```
IF (the_value > overall_average and index_value > 100) THEN `quadrant` = "Priority One"
ELSEIF (the_value < overall_average and index_value > 100) THEN `quadrant` = "Potential"
ELSEIF (the_value > overall_average and index_value < 100) THEN `quadrant` = "Basics"
ELSEIF (the_value < overall_average and index_value < 100) THEN `quadrant` = "Ignore"
```

Can you help me come up with a complete query for this? I'm also open to manipulating the data in PHP after it's returned from the database if that's simpler.

Comment: Have you used `group by` in your sql statement yet? `avg()` is an aggregate function and necessitates the use of `group by` on all columns that also don't contain an aggregate function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CASE clause:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column2 as alias,..., 
CASE
    WHEN the_value > overall_average and index_value > 100 THEN 'Priority One'
    ...
    WHEN another_condition THEN 'Potential'
    ...
    ELSE 'default value'
END AS quadrant
FROM table
```

Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: Do I add this before my `SELECT`

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should add CASE expression just as a column in your SELECT

Comment: Okay...what I end up with is this entire thing being returned instead of just the value: `CASE quadrant
    WHEN the_value > overall_average and index_value > 100 THEN 'Priority One'...`